# Unknown argument on a function on github

Tags: php, image, function, github, upload

I found a good function on github for uploading images using php, but I do not know one of its arguments.

```
upload_image($_FILES,'file',250,'city',500,'../../uploaded/',1048576);
```

[Function on Github](https://github.com/MohammadKermani/php-image-upload)

1. What is 'file' in this function?
2. Is this a trusted function to use in my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering [the lines](https://github.com/MohammadKermani/php-image-upload/blob/3e7b9ff09ef1574debbae26bd90052866a675f1d/upload_image.php#L7-L32):

```
$file[$fileIndex]['tmp_name']
$file[$fileIndex]['error']
$file[$fileIndex]['name']
$file[$fileIndex]['type']
$file[$fileIndex]['size']
```

`$file` is [a three-dimensional array](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php), composed of arrays of `name`, `tmp_name`, `type`, `size`, `error`.
It is the kind of array you see when [uploading files in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

It calls [`move-uploaded-file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), which moves an uploaded file to a new location.

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism).
>   If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by `destination`.

Comment: Thanks, What about my second question? I think this is a new function on Github, Can I trust it, that does not have star or fork!

Comment: @TESTinger I don't know: you would have to test it

Comment: I am not professional, What do you think about it's coding? is that professional and can I trust it? (In point of your view)

Comment: @TESTinger it depends on what you intent to use it (see my edited answer): it "doesn't upload to GitHub" nor does it upload images. It rather check what was uploaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tested that function that was great. and yes it is uploading to the place what you need with address 6th argument. I am going to use it for my website.